# How can I make an actual heart symbol in a text on my htc inspire?

Tags: sms, special-chars

I've recieved text message where the the heart wasn't <3 but an actual heart symbol and I have an HTC inspire, how do I send one like that?

Comment: Sounds like you're missing what's called an emoji plugin that is usually available in stock vanilla android. :)

Answer (score 4):

1. You can us3 character application. (Search at play market)
2. Use hackers keyboard (free at play market) - at landscape mode long press on button 3 allows to select: #|³|¾|⅜|♥|♠|♦|♣.

Answer (score 1):

SlideIT keyboard has a heart symbol

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using unicode: U+2764 ♥

Another way is to use image replacement, this would be dependant on the messaging app to replace a specific sequence of letters with the appropriate smiley.

Comment: How does one "use Unicode"? I.e., what did you type to make that symbol?

Comment: What I usually do is I googled for the name of the character, and then copy it to use. It works well for me since I don't use unicode that often. If you're using unicode heavily, there's Unicode Keyboard in the Play Market, which allows you to enter any unicode character by searching for their name or entering the unicode number (2764 for HEAVY BLACK HEART).

Answer (score -2):

An easier way and free of any encoding...

```
<3
```

Simple eh? :)

Comment: What's wrong with it? in fact its extremely portable and free of any android plugins or emojis that are unique to certain ROMs...

Comment: Guess because the question already mentioned this -- and the OP wants something different?

Comment: Because they specifically said they didn't want that.

Comment: Fair enough! That could be a HTC thing deep in that HTC's ROM... ah well :) :D No pleasing people at all! :D